# How to share same instance of domain model in Angular2, and propagate changes?

Tags: typescript, angular

So i have a very simple domain model Shell :

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class Shell {

    public loggedIn: boolean = false;

    Change(item : boolean) {
        this.loggedIn = item;
    }
}
```

I have an AppComponent which hold this property:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [TemplateRef],
    templateUrl: './angular/app/Index.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgIf],
    viewProviders: [Shell]
})



export class AppComponent {

    public Shell: Shell

    constructor( @Inject(Shell) _shell: any) {
        this.Shell = _shell;
    }
}
```

and short piece of index view :

```
<div *ngIf="Shell.loggedIn">
    LOGGED IN!
</div>
```

and i have a registerview which wants to change loggedin status on successful registration:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './Angular/app/Html/Account/Register.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [AccountService],
    viewProviders: [Shell]
})

export class RegisterView {
    registerForm: any;
    public Shell: Shell
    model = new RegisterVM();
    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private _http: Http,
        private _accountSerivce: AccountService,
        @Inject(Shell) _shell: any) {
        this.Shell = _shell
    }

    onSubmit(event: any) {
        this.Shell.Change(true)
    }
```

As you can see i attempted to make use of dependency injection, but every single time Shell is returned as a new object.

Do i really need to make Shell singleton? or are there any other ways? I am very new to angular2 so i might have overseen some very basic things, please correct me if i messed up anywhere.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by propagate changes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36267274/217408 might be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to add your Shell service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ Shell ]);
```

And remove it from all viewProviders attribute of your components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [TemplateRef],
    templateUrl: './angular/app/Index.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgIf],
    // viewProviders: [Shell] <-------
})
```

It's because of the way the "hierarchical injectors" feature of Angular2 works. For more details you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to make Shell a singleton. You have to add the service in your bootstrap method as a provider.