# Angular service call function in component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

So I know you can have two unrelated components communicate with each other via a service by having one component emit an event in the service and the other subscribe to it in the service.

My question:

Can a service call a function in a component directly?

Comment: If you have a reference in your service to the component, sure. But I wouldn't recommend the two classes referring to each other.

Comment: so basically the event throwing and subscribing method is best practice?

Comment: Definetely. You can do that with observers. You want to keep it seperated in order to keep separations of concerns. The answer of Günter seems to be correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not by default. A service is an instance of a class, nothing more.

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  ...
)}
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService:MyService) {}
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [MyService],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This way a service (`MyService`) instance gets passed to `MyComponent` but that is all. The service instance has no knowledge about `MyComponent`.

What you probably want is to add an `Observable` to your service and subscribe to it in your component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  ...
)}
class MyComponent {
  constructor(myService:MyService) {
    myService.someObservable.subscribe(value => doSomething(value));
  }

  doSomething(value) {
    console.debug(value);
  }
}
```

this way the service "calls" a method on the component when the `Observable` `someObservable` emits another value.

For more details see [detect change of nested property for component input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267119/detect-change-of-nested-property-for-component-input/36267274#36267274)

Comment: You must ensure the injected MyService in component and the one in other place refer to the same object. Otherwise, the component will fail to respond to the MyService's event.

Comment: That is by providing it not directoly at the component but on a common parent (or `AppComponent` which is the common parent of the whole application, or in `bootstrap()`)

Comment: You are right. I just notice others. you get a nice solution.

Comment: Better solution would be to use Subject instead of Observers/ables. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md

Comment: It would be more helpful if you code provide the service `someObservable` code too

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct except that you don't bootstrap your service, you will add your service in your providers array in the app.module.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [],
    providers: [MyService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Then you inject your service inside of the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

import { MyService } from './path/to/my.service'

...

export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private myService:MyService){}

}
```