# Change value of html template in angular 2 from outer component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am going to create an online shopping site using angular 2.
I got a cart in the navigation menu and i want to update the cart value when user add product in the cart.
My can pass the value between component but can't update this value in the html template. My code example hear:-

```
nav.component
```

```js
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItem = 5;

  constructor(private cartService:CartServiceService) {
    this.cartItem = this.cartService.cartItem;
   }

}
```

```
nav template
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a routerLink="/details">Details</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Cart <span>{{cartItem}}</span> </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

the navigation menu looks like
[image]

I got a component call home component and home component have a button.
when home component click to button the Cart menu automatically will update.

```
home component
```

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cartItem: number;

  constructor(private cartService: CartServiceService) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  click() {
    this.cartService.cartChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.cartService.cartItem = 10;
    })
  }

}
```

And finally the service

```
cart service
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class CartServiceService {

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.cartItem);
   }
  
  cartItem:number = 1;
  cartChange:Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  changeCart() {
    this.cartItem = 5;
    this.cartChange.next(this.cartItem);
  }

}
```

and i call this service in the `app-module` `providers: [CartServiceService]`

> How can i update the cart in the navbar ??

Comment: Are you  binding the changeCart() function to the button? can we see the code for that in the html?

Comment: changeCart() use in cart service.
in home component template
<button (click)="click()">text</button>

Comment: It should be <button (click)="changeCart()">

Comment: i got an error
ERROR TypeError: co.changeCart is not a function ......

Comment: There's ya problem, it can't access the function to change the cart. I seem to remember something about having to create a parent class to share functions. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309837/angular-2-service-call-function-in-component

Comment: oops that was my fault.
Thank you so much sir.