# How to call a function in a component from service directly?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

Is there any option to execute method in a component from a service directly?

```
@Component({
  selector:'component'
})
export class Component{
  function2(id){ 
    console.log('ID printed '+ id);
  }
}


@Injectable()

export class Service {
  callfunction2() {
    //how?;
      }
}
```

Comment: No, because that would be the opposite of how components and services should interact (components should call services, not vice-versa).

Comment: Technically it is possible with injectors, but don't do it (for the reasons listed in the comment above)

Comment: any alternative solution ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular service call function in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309837/angular-service-call-function-in-component)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call a component function from a service.

You could however create a Subject in the service, and subscribe to it from the component.

In that case once `callfunction2` is passed, it emits the id value on the Subject, and any components that subscribe to this Subject will receive the value

```
@Component({
  selector:'component'
})
export class Component{

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  function2(id){
    this.service.subject.subscribe(id => {
        console.log('ID printed ' + id);
    });
  }
}


@Injectable()

export class Service {

  public subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  callfunction2(id) {
    this.subject.next(id);
  }
}
```